# Quoting column names with NHibernate and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate

I have started to use NHibernate 3.0 and PostgreSQL for a small project, so far the ride has been a little rough due to the NHibernate site being down and I'm sure this answer is on their website somewhere.

I have a database that has these two columns(of course there is more in the real table):

```
int ID
String Feature
```

now I'm using a FluentNHibernate to do the mapping so something like this:

```
public class MyEntityMap: ClassMap<MyEntity>
{
    public MyEntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Feature);
    }
}
```

and a LINQ query to get out the data

```
var strucs = from str in session.Query<MyEntity>()
             where str.ID < 5
             select str;
```

The query will generate the proper SQL statement, well sort of. The problem is, because I have uppercase letters in my column names you have to wrap them in quotes but the generated SQL code looks something like this:

```
SELECT this_.ID as ID0_0_, this_.feature as feature0_0_, 
       FROM "MyEntity" this_ WHERE this_.ID < 5
```

Where the columns don't have quotes around them.  If I run this I get a "column this_.id" is not found etc.

Does anyone know how I can get NHibernate to wrap the column names in quotes?

**EDIT:** I can't lowercase the column names as there are some columns that a third party program needs to be all in uppercase.

I tried adding .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords","auto-quote") but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [hbm2ddl.keywords](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/auto-quote-tablecolumn-names.html) is supposed to do this for you and it not working, I would suggest you to grab [nhibernate source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.0.0Alpha1/NHibernate-3.0.0.Alpha1-src.zip/download), and debug it with your project.

Problably you can start with a breakpoint on SessionFactoryImpl.cs line 171

```
if (settings.IsAutoQuoteEnabled)
```

Take a look at method *public static void QuoteTableAndColumns(Configuration configuration)* on SchemaMetadataUpdater.cs

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm it throws a error on `public override IDataBaseSchema GetDataBaseSchema(DbConnection connection)` because the `PostgreSQLDialect` doesn't override it to provide one, so the code at `if (settings.IsAutoQuoteEnabled)` throws an exception and they just ignore it.  I wonder why nobody has implemented that method for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction, I implemented my own quick GetDataBaseSchema for PostgreSQLDialect and it seems to be working alright now.

Comment: @Nathan, could you share the solution please?

Comment: FYI, the code in SchemaMetadataUpdater only adds quotes to "reserved" words for your RDBMS. All other words will remain un-quoted.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is a rather old question but for others that may end up here you could also implement a custom naming strategy, when setting up your session factory you would add:

```
Fluently.Configure(new Configuration()
    .SetNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy()))...
```

In CustomNamingStrategy, implement the interface NHibernate.Cfg.INamingStrategy and for all the methods basically just return the parameters with quotes around them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use uppercase characters in table/column names. That will solve this problem and make ad-hoc querying less painful as you won't have to keep quoting them.

Comment: The only problem is another program (not made by me) has to have one of the columns in uppercase :(