# Why can't I call BuildSessionFactory since the update from NHibernate 2 to 3.3.1?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, notsupportedexception

Today I updated my project to NHibernate 3.3 and replaced the NHibernate and the Iesi.Collections References.

I kept NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
I removed the line 
`<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>` from my application config.
Now I get the error NotSupportedException in the last line of the following code:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I googled a lot but I don't have a clue what's wrong. And ideas? Thanks!

my config:

```
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
  <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=myserverip;Port=myport;database=my_test;User Id=my_user;Password=mypwd;CommandTimeout=1;</property>
  <!--<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>-->
  <property name="command_timeout">0</property>
</session-factory>
```

Comment: Please post your nHibernate section from your web.conig/xml file ta

Comment: it get's stranger ... I readded the two files and now it works. Yesterday that didn't help :/ anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just add this line to your xml config

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>
```

More details described here:
[C# / Postgres / FluentNHibernate : configuring npgsql throws NotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532236/c-sharp-postgres-fluentnhibernate-configuring-npgsql-throws-notsupportedex)