# Why Can't I insert this into MySQL InnoDB table using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

Here is my fluent classmap:

```
class ImportedAccountsMap : ClassMap<ImportedAccounts>
{
    public ImportedAccountsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Acct_FName);
        Map(x => x.Acct_LName);
        Map(x => x.Acct_Phone1);
        Map(x => x.Acct_Email);
        Map(x => x.Date);
        Map(x => x.Exists);
        Map(x => x.Deleted);
    }
}
```

And my controller code

```
     public void ImportInsertTest()
    {
        using (ISession session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                ImportedAccounts ia = new ImportedAccounts();
                ia.Date = "test";
                ia.Deleted = false;
                ia.Exists = false;
                ia.Acct_FName = "test";
                ia.Acct_LName = "test";
                ia.Acct_Email = "test@test.com";
                session.Save(ia);
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Exists, Deleted) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test@test.com', 'test', 0, 0)' at line 1"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar error, when my entity property names were equal to keywords of the used database dialect. I don't know the dialect of MySQL, but the property Exists or/and Deleted may cause the problem.

Rename your properties or rename the columns like:

```
Map(x => x.Deleted).Column("IsDeleted");
```

If this is no option for you, there is also a way to turn on quoting for keywords. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332312/quoting-column-names-with-nhibernate-and-postgresql).

Comment: I had figured this out and was going to put an answer, but I'd rather give you the credit for the time you used to answer. Thank you sir.